# What is the difference between these two SSHD configs?

Tags: sshd

## 1

```
Match Group GROUPNAME, User *,!root
```

## 2

```
Match Group GROUPNAME User !root
```

**My question:** What is the difference between #1 and #2 in the SSHD_CONFIG?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The value `!root` alone doesn't match anything.

The value `!root,*` matches everything except `root`.

The man page is not clear about that but it may be that the order matters i.e. `*,!root` would be the same like `*` because the `*` would match and the rest is not checked any more.

Comment: So they differ? :O

Comment: @user74180 Yes.

Comment: @HaukeLaging, are you really sure about this?  The Match section in `sshd_config(5)` and the PATTERNS section in `ssh_config(5)` seem to disagree with this accepted answer by my reading of them.

Comment: @arielf I haven't tried it. Otherwise I wouldn't have written "may". The `!root,*` is from the man page. What exactly do you mean?

Comment: I mean that just by reading the man pages, Raza's answer sounds correct.  Of course, to really be sure someone should actually verify it before answering :)

Answer (score 4):

according to this [reference](http://www.openssh.com/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=sshd_config),
The match patterns may consist of single entries or comma-separated lists and may use the wildcard and negation operators described in the PATTERNS..

Therefore, it should be the same.

Comment: Are you sure it's the same? :O

Comment: The openssh man page says ***By default, login is allowed for all groups*** this seems to imply that `*` at the beginning is redundant because it is the default, and `!root` is the same as `*,!root`.